# VBA Plugin Err: "Requested type library or wizard is not a VBA project"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created an .ade from an adp without problems. 
When I try to open the .ade file I get the following error:
"Requested type library or wizard is not a VBA project" 
The following files are my project:

- Lib.ade (Version 1): external library
- MainProgram.ade: compiled and made ade when the reference is to Version 1 and it works fine.

I sent these two file to client station without any problems but when I did some new changes and make new Lib.ade (Version 2) and sent to client environment, MainProgram (Version 1) gave the mentioned error.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's the limitation of the smartness of using library files. When updated, then all main applications using the library must be recompiled using the updated library file.

Comment: There is no any way to recompile .ade?, and could you please give me a reference about that limitations because I search a lot without any result.

Comment: Sorry, no reference. It's just "common knowledge" learned the hard way by all developers going this route. So, distribute the freshly compiled main file library file as a pair.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message and it turned out to be a "Phantom Breakpoint" issue. See my posting here for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56565372/5795793

After several debug sessions in the original file (an ACCDB file in my case), it started breaking to a code line where I had previously, mistakenly left a breakpoint.  Even though no breakpoint appeared, I had to duplicate the sub and comment out the original sub for it to work.

Sounds like there might be a phantom breakpoint in Version 2 of the Lib.ade. If so, copying the code elsewhere and commenting out the old code can work.  Decompililng may also fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I added more detail above.

Comment: If reviewers of this post deem it low quality and/or recommend deletion, please help me by indicating a more appropriate post that connects the error "Requested type library or wizard is not a VBA project" to the phantom breakpoint issue, and I will happily vote up those posts and remove this one. I am a new poster and am just trying to learn how to best help others.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my experiences with the same problem  will help someone.

Error  "Requested type library or wizard is not a VBA project" occurred only in ACCDE,  when trying to switch between tabs in level 2 navigation form. Explored all the options with references to library files, decompiling and recompiling, creating new DB and  suppressing error message.

The only thing that worked for me is:

1. in ACCDB Remove all VBA code from the navigation form. Event Property Sheet sheet should be cleared of any events.
2. In the Other Property Sheet set "Has Module" to NO. (this should anyway delete the all code in the Navigation Form mentioned in step 1, so perhaps step 1 is not required, but better safe than sorry)
3. Save, Compact&Repair, Compile, Save as ACCDE

Enjoy.